# How to control the scope for setting variables

Tags: expl3, scoping

Why am I not getting `|col. 1|col. 2| ... etc`? Obviously I am not controlling the scope for setting the `\l_rn_i_int` variable correctly, but am unable to determine where I am going wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 19 November 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_rn_i_int  %  local, for looping

\tl_new:N \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_buildVariable_fr:n #1
%  PARAMETER:  #1 the number of entries per row  
%  RETURNS: \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
  {
\group_begin:
  \tl_gclear:N \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {|}
  \int_set:Nn \l_rn_i_int {1}
  \int_until_do:nNnn {\l_rn_i_int} > {#1}
    {
      \int_use:N \l_rn_i_int\\
      \tl_gput_right:Nn ~\fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {col.~\int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |}
      \int_incr:N \l_rn_i_int
    }
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_buildVariable_fr:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myTLVariable{O{5}}
%  PARAMETER:  #1 nr of items in \tl_ variable
  {
\group_begin:
  MWE\\
  \rn_buildVariable_fr:n {#1}
  \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
\group_end:
  }  %  \myTLVariable
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myTLVariable
  \myTLVariable[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Variable names should be of the form `\l_`, `\g_` or `\c_` (local, global or constant), with doubling of the underscore if the variable is private. What should `\fr_` stand for?

Comment: @egreg My way of indicating that a `\cs_` function returns a value. So, I give the function name a suffix `_fr` (for `function return`) and the associated returned variable (always understood to be a global variable) a prefix `\fr_`.  I will modify this practice by prefixing `\g_fr_` in line with `LaTeX3` usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add

```
\tl_show:N \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
```

You see

```
> \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl=macro:
->|col. \int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |col. \int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |col. \int_use:N \l
_rn_i_int |col. \int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |col. \int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |.
\rn_buildVariable_fr:n ...\fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
```

so although you are building up the list you are just putting in multiple references to `\l_rn_i_int` which all give 0 by the time you use them.

change `n` to `x` and you get

```
> \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl=macro:
->|col. 1|col. 2|col. 3|col. 4|col. 5|.
```

so

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 19 November 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_rn_i_int  %  local, for looping

\tl_new:N \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_buildVariable_fr:n #1
%  PARAMETER:  #1 the number of entries per row  
%  RETURNS: \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
  {
\group_begin:
  \tl_gclear:N \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {|}
  \int_set:Nn \l_rn_i_int {1}
  \int_until_do:nNnn {\l_rn_i_int} > {#1}
    {
      \int_use:N \l_rn_i_int\\
      \tl_gput_right:Nx \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {col.~\int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |}
      \int_incr:N \l_rn_i_int
    }
\tl_show:N \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_buildVariable_fr:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myTLVariable{O{5}}
%  PARAMETER:  #1 nr of items in \tl_ variable
  {
\group_begin:
  MWE\\
  \rn_buildVariable_fr:n {#1}
  \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
\group_end:
  }  %  \myTLVariable
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myTLVariable
  \myTLVariable[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works fine, except that my code, from which above MWE is a cut-down version, also has `\tl_gput_right:Nx \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {\hline}` in the mix, which then produces a compilation ERROR: `! Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.` Had I realized it's the `\hline` terms that cause the problem I would have included them in the MWE. If you were to clear up that additional problem for me I would be glad to tick your response as the answer.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth You can do `\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \rn_hline: { \hline }` and then use `\rn_hline:` in your code, which will prevent expansion. EDIT: Wait... couldn't you just use `:Nn` rather than `:Nx` to add `\hline`?

Comment: ... this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 4):

You use

```
\tl_gput_right:Nx \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {|}
```

where the `x` does nothing, but

```
\tl_gput_right:Nn ~\fr_rn_buildVariable_tl {col.~\int_use:N \l_rn_i_int |}
```

when you should use `\tl_gput_right:Nx` instead, in order to expand `\int_use:N`. The `~` after `\tl_gput_right:Nn` ( or `\tl_gput_right:Nx`) should be removed.

The prefix `\fr` is not among the recommended ones for variables: `\l`, `\g` or `\c` (local, global or constant).

It's not clear why you're using double grouping, in `\rn_buildVariable_fr:n` and in `\myTLVariable`. Also the loop you're using can be simplified with `\int_step_inline:nnnn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 19 November 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_rn_buildVariable_tl

\cs_new:Npn \rn_buildVariable_fr:n #1
 {
  %  PARAMETER:  #1 the number of entries per row  
  %  RETURNS: \fr_rn_buildVariable_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_rn_buildVariable_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_buildVariable_tl {|}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    ##1 \\
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_buildVariable_tl {col.~##1|}
   }
 }  %  \rn_buildVariable_fr:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myTLVariable{O{5}}
 {
  %  PARAMETER:  #1 nr of items in \tl_ variable
  MWE\\
  \rn_buildVariable_fr:n {#1}
  \tl_use:N \l_rn_buildVariable_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myTLVariable

\myTLVariable[8]

\end{document}
```

In the fourth argument to `\int_step_inline:nnnn` the current value in the loop implicit variable is available as `#1`, which here becomes `##1` because we're in a definition.

Add grouping, if you really need it.

[image]

Comment: @David Carlisle My MWE was a very reduced version of what I was trying to achieve, namely to automate the creation of `tabular environments`. The `formatting` section was easy, just needed a loop that assembles the required number of `c`, `l` etc. characters with or without `|`s. With your help I now realize that it was the `\hline` terms that caused the problem with `\tl_gput_right:Nx ...`, but that is now resolved by simply using `\tl_gput_right:Nn ...` for them and `\tl_gput_right:Nx ...` for the index. As for the double grouping, I agree, too much of a good thing.